# accessing shared excel sheets via REST API

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, office365-restapi

I can access and modify the excel sheets that are on my drive, but is it possible to do the same for files that some other people own but for which I have read/write access? It's not clear to me how to go about that.

Comment: I have the same issue and it remains unanswered. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/76868871?noredirect=1
I believe no one micorosft graph team is monitoring this forum.